# How can I save global application variables in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, global-variables

In WPF, where can I **save a value** when in one UserControl, then later in another UserControl **access that value** again, something like session state in web programming, e.g.:

**UserControl1.xaml.cs:**

```
Customer customer = new Customer(12334);
ApplicationState.SetValue("currentCustomer", customer); //PSEUDO-CODE
```

**UserControl2.xaml.cs:**

```
Customer customer = ApplicationState.GetValue("currentCustomer") as Customer; //PSEUDO-CODE
```

## ANSWER:

Thanks, Bob, here is the code that I got to work, based on yours:

```
public static class ApplicationState
{
    private static Dictionary<string, object> _values =
               new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public static void SetValue(string key, object value)
    {
        if (_values.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            _values.Remove(key);
        }
        _values.Add(key, value);
    }
    public static T GetValue<T>(string key)
    {
        if (_values.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return (T)_values[key];
        }
        else
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

To save a variable:

```
ApplicationState.SetValue("currentCustomerName", "Jim Smith");
```

To read a variable:

```
MainText.Text = ApplicationState.GetValue<string>("currentCustomerName");
```

Comment: Guess you did not understand what I meant by static class...guess I will have to elaborate more next time.

Comment: Dictionary is not thread-safe, this would not be a viable solution if you plan on accessing ApplicationState from multiple thread.

Comment: @J.Mitchell He can use  ConcurrentDictionary

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
public static class ApplicationState 
{ 
    private static Dictionary<string, object> _values =
               new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public static void SetValue(string key, object value) 
    {
        _values.Add(key, value);
    }

    public static T GetValue<T>(string key) 
    {
        return (T)_values[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do we going to implement this class?  and is this implementation Thread Safe ?

Answer (score 14):

[The Application class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743714.aspx#The_Application_Class) already has this functionality built in.

```
// Set an application-scope resource
Application.Current.Resources["ApplicationScopeResource"] = Brushes.White;
...
// Get an application-scope resource
Brush whiteBrush = (Brush)Application.Current.Resources["ApplicationScopeResource"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can expose a public static variable in App.xaml.cs file and then access it anywhere using App class..

Answer (score 0):

Could just store it yourself in a static class or repository that you can inject to the classes that need the data.