# Wpf application variable not changing

Tags: c#, wpf, properties

In my application I need some variables on almost all the pages so I declared them in Application.xaml like

```
<sys:String x:key="First">First</sys:String>
```

and on one page I change the value in code like

```
Resources["First"] = "This is First";
```

on the second page when I call the variable like

```
String f = (string)this.TryFindResource("First");
MessageBox.Show(f);
```

the out put is "First" and not "This is First". I also tried like.

```
Application.Current.Properties["First"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910421/how-can-i-save-global-application-variables-in-wpf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910421/how-can-i-save-global-application-variables-in-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Binding for such scenarios.

If you want the value to be globally available, make it static and then access it like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static local:MyGlobalClass.First}" />
```